# Datastax Cassandra - Cqlsh with SSL not working

Tags: ssl, cassandra, datastax

I've installed a single-node Datastax Cassandra v3.5 cluster on my Ubuntu machine. I'm trying to connect to the node using the command-line interface cqlsh using the SSL option without success (from the same machine). The steps I followed are:

- Prepared the .keystore, .cer certificate and .truststore following this guide http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secureSSLCertificates_t.html
- Modified my cassandra.yaml accordingly:

  `client_encryption_options:
      enabled: true
      optional: false
      keystore: /************************/.keystore
      keystore_password: ************************
      require_client_auth: false
      # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
      truststore: /************************/.truststore
      truststore_password: ************************`
- Created a cqlshrc conf file and filled it following this guide https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureCqlshSSL_t.html :

  `[connection]
  hostname = *****
  port = 9042
  factory = cqlshlib.ssl.ssl_transport_factory
  [ssl]
  certfile = /home/conf/mycert.cer
  validate = true ## Optional, true by default`

So basically I created a private and public key, pointed Cassandra to my .keystore and .truststore (even tho I don't think it's necessary because I'm not enforcing the client auth) and cqlsh to the public key (certificate).

Whenever I try to launch `cqlsh --ssl` I get always the same error and not a single debug message inside Cassandra. The error message is:

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers',
>   {'***.*****.******': error(0, "Tried connecting to
>   [('**.**.***.***', 9042)]. Last error: _ssl.c:344:error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)")})

Just a side note, if I remove SSL authentication everything works perfectly.

### **EDIT**

I've solved my initial issue following @Adam Holmberg suggestion but still no luck with the SSL connection. I checked that I have JCE libraries installed and I've been trying to enforce cqslh to use SSLv23 or TLSv1 to establish the connection to the Cassandra server but I receive the following error all the times:

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', ... ... ...
>   Last error: _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol")})

Moreover, I've also added the JVM option -Djavax.net.debug=all to no avail, I don't see any additional log about ssl.

Comment: Did you install the JCE libraries?

Comment: Just a thought, but do you need to support two-way SSL?  If not, try setting `validate = false` in both your cqlshrc and cassandra.yaml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error and some useful hints gave by @Adam and @Aaron (thanks for the help) I managed to finally establish an SSL connection between cqlsh and my Cassandra server instance.

After pondering about the issue, I came to the conclusion that there was some kind of additional configuration error in both client and server and to help other people that may face the same issue I'll post here my final configuration:

**cqlshrc**

```
[connection]
hostname = *****.*****.*****.*****.*****
port = 9042

[cql]
version = 3.4

[tracing]
max_trace_wait = 10.0

[ssl]
certfile = /****/****/****/****.cer.pem
validate = false ## Optional, true by default
#version = SSLv23
#factory = cqlshlib.ssl.ssl_transport_factory
```

**cassandra.yaml (relevant part)**

```
# enable or disable client/server encryption.
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    # If enabled and optional is set to true encrypted and unencrypted connections are handled.
    optional: false
    keystore: /***/****/****/.keystore
    keystore_password: *********
    require_client_auth: false
    # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
    truststore: /****/****/****/.truststore
    truststore_password: ****
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLSv1
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming "/home/conf/mycert.cer" is the file you created during server configuration, that is not the right format for Python (cqlsh). You need to export it in PEM format for Python:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <alias> -keypass <pass> -keystore <keystore> -storepass <pass> -rfc -file cassandra_cert.pem
```

If you're just experimenting with cqlsh and are not concerned about true security, you can also omit those options (validate, certfile) from cqlshrc and connect with no cert validation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I'm facing another error : `Last error: _ssl.c:510: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number")})`, looks like there is an SSL version mismatch between Cassandra and cqlsh.. how can that be?

Comment: As Aaron mentioned, make sure you have JCE unlimited strength policy files installed, restart the server. You can experiment with explicitly setting the version [client-side](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.5/pylib/cqlshlib/sslhandling.py#L64), but the defaults should work. You may also want to turn on [ssl debugging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) in java to get better insight.

Comment: Still no luck. I had JCE already, tried to play with the python ssl script but nothing works.. eventually I'm getting this error when I enforce SSLv23 or TLSv1 in cqlsh config file : `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', ... ... ... Last error: _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol")})`.

Comment: Some googling would suggest that this error is sometimes associated with the client not using TLSv1. If you want to get into troubleshooting mode you could verify what ssl_options are being set [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.5/bin/cqlsh.py#L740-L746). There's also the suggestion (above) to turn on ssl debugging server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error:
*Last error: [SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:727)*

What have solved this was adding the line of the SSL version at cqlshrc file:

```
[connection]
(...)
version = SSLv23
```